Infinite Loop in Angular 17 OIDC Setup with AutoLoginPartialRouteGuard and checkAuth() Failing on Redirect URI with Hash
I’m working on an Angular 17 standalone app with OIDC authentication using angular-auth-oidc-client version of 18.0.1. The app runs on http://localhost:4200, and I’ve configured app.config.ts as shown below. I’ve implemented AutoLoginPartialRouteGuard on routes, except for my callback route, as this is my redirect_uri.
The problem occurs after the OIDC authentication redirect. The app gets stuck in an infinite loop on the redirect URI, which includes a hash in the URL (http://localhost:4200/callback#access_token=fads798asd7as9).
In my callback.component.ts oidcService.checkAuth() consistently returns false. Interestingly, this same configuration works correctly in another repository, and I’m unsure what might be causing the issue here.
app.config.ts
 ProvideAuth({
  config: {
    authority: "{authority_url}",
    redirectUrl: `${window.location.origin}/callback`,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
    clientId: "MyClient",
    scope: "openid profile email offline_access",
    responseType: "id_token token",
    silentRenew: true,
    useRefreshToken: true,
    silentRenewUrl: `${window.location.origin}/silent-renew.html`,
    renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 30,
    logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
    startCheckSession: true,
    customPramsAuthRequest: {
      auth_method: oidc.authMehtod,
      realm: oidc.realm,
      ttl: oidc.ttl,
    },
  },
});

app.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AutoLoginPartialRouteGuard], // Guard applied for authenticated routes
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    canActivate: [AutoLoginPartialRouteGuard], // Securing the dashboard with the guard
  },
  {
    path: 'callback',
    component: CallbackComponent, // Callback route for handling redirections
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '', // Catch-all route
  }
];

callback.component.ts
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.oidcService.checkAuth().subscribe((result) => {
      if (result.isAuthenticated) {
        // If the user is authenticated, redirect to the desired page (e.g., dashboard)
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      } else {
        // Handle cases where authentication fails
        console.log('User is not authenticated');
        // Optionally redirect to a login page or show an error message
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    }, (error) => {
      // Handle errors during the authentication check
      console.error('Error during authentication check', error);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);  // Redirect to home or a login page
    });
  }
}


Maybe the observable is returning a boolean and not an object, hence, you are getting a console error and redirected, since the redirect happens, you are unable to see the console.error.
Reference Github Project
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.oidcService.checkAuth().subscribe((isAuthenticated) => { // <- changed here!
      if (isAuthenticated) { // <- changed here!
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      } else {
        console.log('User is not authenticated');
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    }, (error) => {
      console.error('Error during authentication check', error);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);  
    });
  }


Thanks for the reply @naren-murali. checkAuth will be return LoginResponse it's an object even i tried to check in this isAuthenticated it returns false.

I found the issue was due to a recent version update. In my package.json, I had specified "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^18.0.1", but after checking the node_modules, it had been updated to version 18.0.2 (18.0.1 to 18.0.2). After reverting and running npm install, everything worked as expected.
